# Mock object fails to return required object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, moq, ninject-2

There is bound to be something obvious I'm overlooking - there usually is when I have problems like this.

I have a controller that simply returns a news article based on a supplied ID:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IArticleRepository articleRepository;

    public HomeController(IArticleRepository Repository)
    {
        articleRepository = Repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    // Here's the bit we're interested in
    public ActionResult Article(int id)
    {
        var article = articleRepository.GetById(id);

        return View("Article", article);
    }

}
```

I'm mocking this using Moq like so:

```
[TestFixture]
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    HomeController controller;
    int articleId;
    Article model;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetupMethods()
    {
        Mock<IArticleRepository> repositoryMock = new Mock<IArticleRepository>();
        repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(articleId)).Returns(GetSampleArticle());

        controller = new HomeController(repositoryMock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Article_Action_Returns_Requested_Article()
    {
        // Arrange
        model = new Article();
        articleId = 1;

        // Act
        ActionResult result = controller.Article(articleId);

        // Assert
        var viewResult = ((ViewResult)result);
        var returnedModel = viewResult.Model;
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<Article>(viewResult.Model);
        //Assert.AreEqual(articleId, returnedModel.ID);
    }
}
```

The "GetSampleArticle" method in question above just looks like this:

```
    private Article GetSampleArticle()
    {
        Article article = new Article()
        {
            Archived = false,
            Body = "<p>This is a dummy sample article for use in our mocks.</p>",
            EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30),
            ID = 1,
            Priority = 3,
            StartDate = DateTime.Today,
            Title = "Sample Article"
        };

        return article;
    }
```

However I'm still getting a null type for the model. So what have I forgotten?

```
News.Tests.Controllers.HomeControllerTests.Article_Action_Returns_Requested_Article:
  Expected: instance of <News.Data.Article>
  But was:  null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another idea is to use the It.IsAny() method to avoid having to look for a hardcoded value at all:

```
repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(GetSampleArticle());
```

Which is safe to do since you're not concerned with the actual value of the articleId so much as the mechanics of its retrieval.

Comment: Agreed completely.  You should not be specifying values for Setup.  Instead you should use Expect() when you want to validate the value itself though even this is something I don't really do myself anymore as a quick read through the code tells me if A is getting assigned to B properly.

Comment: Even better. I always want to learn more about how to better use Moq syntax and this is a really helpful example. Thanks.

Comment: I would advise against using the `IsAny` in Unit Tests, unless you absolutely have to.  It makes the test fragile as you cannot be exactly sure what you are passing in, and you cannot be sure you are returning the correct data.  If you pass `articleId` instead of `IsAny` you know that `GetById` is being called with the correct argument.  It just makes the test more solid, and gives you more confidence that it passes for the right reasons.

Comment: That's good advice and I appreciate it, but in this case since I'm not actually particularly concerned with the actual value being passed; just that a dummy record is being returned, the `IsAny` method should suit just fine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In your SetupMethods, articleId is 0.

In your test, you set it to 1, so your `.Setup` is never being called.  I would move your Setup into your test.

```
[Test]
public void Article_Action_Returns_Requested_Article()
{
    // Arrange
    model = new Article();
    articleId = 1;

    Mock<IArticleRepository> repositoryMock = new Mock<IArticleRepository>();
    repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(articleId)).Returns(GetSampleArticle());

    controller = new HomeController(repositoryMock.Object);

    // Act
    ActionResult result = controller.Article(articleId);

    // Assert
    var viewResult = ((ViewResult)result);
    var returnedModel = viewResult.Model;
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Article>(viewResult.Model);
    //Assert.AreEqual(articleId, returnedModel.ID);
}
```

Comment: Marvellous. Thank you. I actually moved it into the NUnit [SetUp] decorated method instead of declaring it each time for each test. Works just fine.